# How can I create a sidebar menu in Flutter such that selecting a menu changes the main panels widget?

Tags: flutter, observable, sidebar

I am trying to create an application with a sidebar menu in Flutter but don't know how to change the main panels content when one of the menu items is selected.

Here is the basic main screen

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/mainScreen';
  final leftSection = new Container(
    child: new Sidebar(),
  );
  final middleSection = new Expanded(
    child: new DetailPage1(),
  );
  final rightSection = new Container(
    child: new Sidebar(),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[leftSection, middleSection, rightSection],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Sidebar

```
class Sidebar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text(
              'Side menu',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/cover.jpg'))),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.input),
            title: Text('Welcome'),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
            title: Text('Profile'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.border_color),
            title: Text('Feedback'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title: Text('Logout'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I wire things up such that the MainScreen middleSection contents are changed ?

I am thinking of creating some sort of global variable that can have a variable set that MainScreen can observe and then call a function to replace the middleSection's container child.

Does Flutter have some design patterns for doing this ?  Is this even the right approach and if so then:

1. How should global variables be created in Flutter ?
2. How can I observe changes on global variables in Flutter ?

I am familiar with SwiftUI and Combine and ObservableObject and so on - is there a similar construct in Flutter or Dart that can be used to achieve the same thing ?

Thanks

Comment: are you checked this video ?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oExw0U4U_UI

Answer (score 0):

Renavigate to main page with pushReplacement and pass data which you wanna change in main screen:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext    
  context) => MainScreen(
  // pass your data to be changed on main screen
  )));
}
```